# Adding drawing objects to a collection in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, graphics, flex4, markup

I'm trying to make annotations on an image.
 
I want to store all these annotations into a collection so that I can later remove or edit particular note(annotation).

I'm creating a UIComponent instance for example markUp and doing

```
 markUp.graphics.lineStyle(2, drawColor);
 markUp.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
 markUp.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
```

I want to create a UIComponent instance every time whenever user makes a new annotation on my image.

How to generate dynamic instance and how to save them to a collection. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand yet. Do you have a single image or different ones? What exactly does the user? On which event you want to refresh the annotations? Are there multiple instances of annotations for a single image? What should the collection store? x,y,w,h?

Comment: The annotation is text? Your code shows only a drawn line.

Comment: @Jens Struwe -- Yes, I have a Image gallery. An Image may have more than one annotations. I'm trying to save annotations collection image wise so that later I can let my user edit/delete the annotation of a particular image.When a user starts marking on an image I dont want to add this child to image directly. I want to add this annotation to a collection which is added to the image. Through that collection I can remove/edit a particular annotation.

Comment: @Jens Struwe--After every markup I'm giving a popup window to enter text about the annotation. Even I've to save that text too.

Comment: What exactly is shown on the image?

Comment: @Jens Struwe -- Annotations with popupwindows. These popup windows can be minimizable.

Comment: @KishorKumar let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2125/discussion-between-jens-struwe-and-kishor-kumar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand after a chat with Kishor:

Users may mark specific areas by mouse drag and add a comment accordingly. Markup and comment are stored in the database.

There is only one image enlarged at a time, and this image should display all markups. Clicking on a markup will raise a popup showing the associated comment.

Apparently drawing the markup is rather expensive, so once drawn a particular markup should be reused when the user switchs between images. The question is now:

**How to reuse markups displayed on an image?**

Answer:

Use an `Object` or `Dictionary` where you create one entry per image and the entry points to an `Array` of markups. You may create a convenient class to encapsulate the functionality of this map:

```
package {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class Markups {
        private var _map : Object;

        public function Markups() {
            _map = new Object();
        }

        public function addMarkup(imageId : String, markup : DisplayObject) : void {
            if (!_map[imageId]) _map[imageId] = new Array();
            (_map[imageId] as Array).push(markup);
        }

        public function hasMarkups(imageId : String) : Boolean {
            return _map[imageId] !== undefined;
        }

        public function getMarkups(imageId : String) : Array {
            return _map[imageId];
        }

        public function removeMarkup(imageId : String, markup : DisplayObject) : void {
            var markups : Array = _map[imageId];
            var index : int = markups.indexOf(markup);
            markups.splice(index, 1);
            if (!markups.length) delete _map[imageId];
        }
    }
}
```

Store this map at a place that is accessible from your image container.

```
var markupsPerImage : Markups = new Markups();
```

Add or remove a markup like this:

```
markupsPerImage.addMarkup(myImage.id, markupView);
markupsPerImage.removeMarkup(myImage.id, markupView);
```

Whenever the user changes the current image you 1. cleanup all markups of the last and 2. add all markups stored in the map.

In the image container:

```
public function setImage(myImage : MyImage) : void {
    // remove markups
    while (markupContainer.numChildren) {
        markupContainer.removeChildAt(0);
    }
    // add markups
    var markups : Array = markupsPerImage.getMarkups(myImage.id);
    var markup : MarkupView;
    foreach (markups as markup) {
        markupContainer.addChild(markup);
    }
}
```

Notes:

The example code assumes you have a markup container that hosts all markups. This container should have a reference to the markup map.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jens Struwe. Really it's a huge help :)

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to explain or understand a problem. Happy, that I could help you.